# jQuery - getting incorrect ID from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25321/

You can see 3 buttons, each button has `data-entry-id` attribute.

```
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-entry-id="5"> Button 1</button>
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-entry-id="10"> Button 2</button>
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-entry-id="15"> Button 3</button>
```

When you click on a button, it will pass value from `data-entry-id` to BootStrap modal in `Save changes` button (`data-id` attribute). This is how it done:

```
  $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var thisModal = $(this);   
      var entryId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('entry-id');

      $('.btn-save', thisModal).attr('data-id', entryId);
      $('.content-text', thisModal).html("Button Entry ID: " +  entryId);
   });
```

If you click on any button and then click on "Save changes" button from a modal - it will alert id from `data-id` attribute. Problem is, it is not showing correct id when you click on the "Save changes". It does not match `data-id` attribute in the   "Save changes" button. What is causing this?

```
$('body').on("click", ".btn-save", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: don't mix `.data(*,` and `.attr('data-*`. One doesn't update the other.

Comment: Why downvote hmmm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `data-*` with `.data()` and `jQuery.attr` together, use either of them, both are different.

`jQuery.data()` does not manipulate `attribute` and vice-versa

```js
 $(function() {

   $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
     var thisModal = $(this);
     var entryId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('entry-id');
     alert(entryId)
     $('.btn-save', thisModal).attr('data-id', entryId);
     $('.content-text', thisModal).html("Button Entry ID: " + entryId);
   });
 });

 $('body').on("click", ".btn-save", function(event) {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   alert(id);
 });
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/DTcHh/25323/)

Comment: Ahh I see, it is possible to have `$(this).data('id');` to work? I assume I need to replace `.attr('data-id', entryId);` to something?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back — Either stick to `jQuery.data()` while assigning as well as while retrieving or use `jQuery.attr` instead!

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to pass `$(event.relatedTarget)` (button element) to click event? So for example I could change background colour of "Button 2" in `$('body').on("click", ".btn-save", function(event) {}` block.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back – You can! Pass anything using `data-*` attributes or using `jQuery.data()`

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have a clear picture of your code from your question, I can see you are using:

```
$('body').on("click", ".btn-save", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id); 
});
```

I think that when this event handler fires $(this) refers to the body element.
I can assume that since you are trying to save data to the save button, you want to retrieve the id from the save button's data like so:

```
var id = $(e.target).data('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on("click", ".btn-save", function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-entry-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

The data attributes are attributes. So you grab them the same way you'd grab other attributes.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/DTcHh/25324/)

Comment: Jsfiddle was slow to save.. I copied too soon, it's updated now.